# Flutter + Firestore : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to convert a firebase document to a class / model.

First, I run a query:

```
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collectionGroup('myGroup')
      .where('letter', isEqualTo: 'a')
      .getDocuments();
  List results = [];

  snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
    results.add(f.data);
  });
```

Then I would like to 'convert' a certain document to a class / model.

I normally do it with this code:

```
myResult = model.fromDocument(doc);
```

But when I do it now with this code:

```
myResult = model.fromDocument(results[3]);
```

It gives this error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'
```

I saw this stack overflow post: [New: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130622/new-type-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-do)

The problem is: that it works if you add a document and not a document.data

```
snapshot.data[index].data // is of type Map<String,Dynamic>     
snapshot.data[index] // is the DocumentSnapshot
```

How can I convert a doc.data to a model / class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just moved one step close to converting it to model when you did doc.data, now your old conversion inside fromDocument looks like

```
_songId = doc.data['songId'];
```

since now its the doc.data part is gone you just need to call

```
_songId = data['songId'];//data is the value passed through fromDoc as parameter
```

or you could simply modify your old code like this

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> results;

snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
    results.add(f);//removing the .data
  });

//now this code below works just fine

myResult = model.fromDocument(results[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I would really like it to convert it to my model so I can call: model.songId

Comment: I updated the code , added another option check it out I removed the '.data' inside the loop

Comment: ok thanks, but that loop has a specific purpose (that s why it has data in it. And since the index: 3 can Change it would be a lot easier to find a way to “convert” a doc.data to a doc

Comment: yes but if the list is List<DocumentSnapshot> type, it works for any index

Comment: I cant solve your problem without knowing the 'specific purpose' you mentioned, as far as I see its data is reusable as both doc and map.